# JPA auto-ddl , setting Long value length not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_jpa")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id",length = 19)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "length",precision = 10)
private Long length;

@Column(name = "test", length = 19)
private String test;
}
```

Log print:

```
Hibernate: create table test_jpa (id bigint not null, length bigint, test varchar(19), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
```

The length of Long value ,do not work.Also I tried @Size and @Length, same problem.

JPA version:2.6.7
Mysql

Thank you M. Deinum.
I get it, Numeric types no need to set length,They have fixed range.

Comment: Numeric types don't have a max length set unless you use a `BigDecimal` you can specify how much before and after the decimal point. A `Long` will, depending on the database, match to an `integer` type column which doesn't have a length.